# How can i serve pdf download after 10 seconds in django view

Tags: python, django, pdf, download

I have the generic class based view and where when the user click on file name i open the detail page which shows some text of the File

like this

```
class DetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = "file_detail.html"
        model = models.File
```

Now that link opens the page fine.

Now i have the file link like `http://www.example.com/file.pdf`

The way it currently works is that i have the link called download at that page and when some click it downloads because that pdf link is direct link

But i dont want user to click twice . i want that when user click on detail page then after 10 seconds then view automatically serves the dialog of file download to user

That pdf file reside on amazon S3 so i want to directly serve from there and its public. i made the detail view to track downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your javascript for the detailView page you could direct user to download link after 10 seconds

`setTimeout(function() {window.location = '/file.pdf'}, 10000)`